# Total newbie... Need help understanding python classes

Tags: python, class

My understanding of python is zero to none... Been exhausting myself reading what seems like a hundred different ways to approach this. Below I put the assignment description and my code... As of now I am having trouble using the 'getAnimal()' command. I'm not sure what it does or how it works. Thanks in advance :D

Assignment description: "Write a class definition for a class 'Zoo.' It should have instance variables for animal type, herbivore/carnivore/omnivore, and inside/outside. It should also have a getAnimal() method to show the animals information. Write a separate "ZooDriver" class to a) create three instances of zoo animals, b) get user input on which animal to view (1,2,3)c) show the animal info suing getAnimal()."

~~~~~~~~ My code:

```
class Zoo:
def __init__(self, animal, animal_type, habitat):
    self.animal = animal
    self.animal_type = animal_type
    self.habitat = habitat

 user_input=raw_input("Enter the number 1, 2, or 3 for information on an animal.")

 if user_input == "1":
     my_animal = Zoo("Giraffe", "herbivore", "outside")
 elif user_input == "2":
     my_animal = Zoo("Lion", "carnivore", "inside")
 elif user_input == "3":
     my_animal = Zoo("Bear", "omnivore", "inside")

 print "Your animal is a %s, it is a %s, and has an %s habitat." % (my_animal.animal,        my_animal.animal_type, my_animal.habitat)
```

Comment: Your best chance for success on this site is to start with a properly formatted question. Since you are a complete novice, we can't make any assumptions about your code that we might do with more experienced programmers. Please make sure your code appears exactly as it does in your text editor.

Comment: You should set up an appointment with your instructor regarding this question.

Comment: The way you ask questions is of course going to spark answers  of the style _"figure it out, i'm not doing your homework for you"_. Your question consists of a _sad story which is quite irrelevant to the question_ + _please do my homework_. You didn't even make the effort to tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: My issue is that I don't even know what to ask. I really don't even understand what a "class" is and how the different parts of it are defined... Maybe a good first question is am I even using these commands correctly?

Comment: Carsten... if I knew where I was stuck, I would be able to just look it up in a book, or on the powerpoint I was given by my teacher. Am I using the "def __init__()" and the "self.animal =" commands correctly?

Comment: Are you certain you transcribed the assignment correctly? It asks to creat a class `Zoo`, but then seems to describe a class of `Animal`. It then says to create three zoo animals, but doesn't have you create an animal class.

Comment: @Isturite: Your assignment is to create two classes, `Zoo` which basically represents a single generic animal, and `ZooDriver` which represents a generic zoo filled with `Zoo` animals.  I would recommend that you first start with a `Zoo` class that takes as input: animal name, habitat, and diet.  Once the class is made, you can try making `lion = Zoo('lion', 'carnivore', 'outside')`.  Then try accessing its diet and habitat using the `lion` object.  Try this first, then update your question with a *real, relevant* question.  Once you get `Zoo` working, you can start on `ZooDriver`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I copied the assignment description so it is correct to every letter.

Comment: @Bill thank you sooo much! That was extremely helpful! I will do exactly that... but how do I get a class to take input? I would approach that by creating a variable for each cell in the class (such as 'animal_name=input('enter the number 1, 2, or 3')'), but I'm guessing that is wrong

Answer (score 2):

A class defines a *type* of thing. An instance is one *thing* of that type. For example, you could say `Building` is a type of thing.

Let's start with a class named `Building`:

```
class Building():
    pass
```

Now, to create an actual building -- an *instance* -- we call it almost like it was a function:

```
b1 = Building()
b2 = Building()
b3 = Building()
```

There, we just created three buildings. They are identical, which isn't very useful. Maybe we can give it a name when we create it, and store it in an instance variable. That requires creating a *constructor* that takes an argument. All class methods must also take `self` as its first argument, so our constructor will take two arguments:

```
class Building():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now we can create three different buildings:

```
b1 = Building("firehouse")
b2 = Building("hospital")
b3 = Building("church")
```

If we want to create a "driver" class to create three buildings, we can do that pretty easily. If you want to set an instance variable or do some work when you create an instance, you can do that in a constructor. For example, this creates such a class that creates three buildings and stores them in an array:

```
class Town():
    def __init__(self):
        self.buildings = [
            Building("firehouse"),
            Building("hospital"),
            Building("church")
        ]
```

We now can create a single object that creates three other objects. Hopefully that's enough to get you over the initial hurdle of understanding classes.

Answer (score 0):

OK I will try to answer the main question here: What a class is.

```
From Google: class /klas/
             noun: class; plural noun: classes

1.
a set or category of things having some property or attribute in common and
differentiated from others by kind, type, or quality.
```

In programming, a class is just that. say, for example you have class Dog. Dogs bark "ruf ruff".

We can define the dog class in python using just that information.

```
class Dog:
    def bark(self):
        print "ruf ruff"
```

To use the class, it is `instantiated` by calling `()` its constructor:

```
Spot = Dog()
```

We then want Spot to bark, so we call a `method` of the class:

```
Spot.bark()
```

To further explain the details of the code here would be to go outside of the scope of this question.

Further reading:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: Thank you so much for bearing with me on this lol... what exactly does this do? You have class "Dog" and bark is being defined as a charastic of dog? and on what condition is "ruf ruff" being printed?

Comment: thanks a lot... I'm going to mess around with this and see where I get.

Answer (score -1):

As a direct answer:

```
class Zoo(object):
    def __init__(self, name="Python Zoo"):
        self.name = name
        self.animals = list()

    def getAnimal(self,index):
        index = index - 1 # account for zero-indexing
        try:
            print("Animal is {0.name}\n  Diet: {0.diet}\n  Habitat: {0.habitat}".format(
                self.animals[index]))
        except IndexError:
            print("No animal at index {}".format(index+1))

    def listAnimals(self,index):
        for i,animal in enumerate(self.animals, start=1):
            print("{i:>3}: {animal.name}".format(i=i,animal=animal))


class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, diet=None, habitat=None):
        if any([attr is None for attr in [name,diet,habitat]]):
            raise ValueError("Must supply values for all attributes")
        self.name = name
        self.diet = diet
        self.habitat = habitat


class ZooDriver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.zoo = Zoo()
        self.zoo.animals = [Animal(name="Giraffe", diet="Herbivore", habitat="Outside"),
                            Animal(name="Lion", diet="Carnivore", habitat="Inside"),
                            Animal(name="Bear", diet="Herbivore", habitat="Inside")]

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("1. List Animals")
            print("2. Get information about an animal (by index)"
            print("3. Quit")
            input_correct = False
            while not input_correct:
                in_ = input(">> ")
                if in_ in ['1','2','3']:
                    input_correct = True
                    {'1':self.zoo.listAnimals,
                     '2':lambda x: self.zoo.getAnimal(input("index #: ")),
                     '3': self.exit}[in_]()
                else:
                    print("Incorrect input")
    def exit(self):
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ZooDriver().run()
```

I haven't actually run this code so some silly typos may have occurred and the usual "off-by-one" errors (oops), but I'm fairly confident in it. It displays a lot of concepts your instructor won't expect you to have mastered yet (such as string formatting, most likely, and almost certainly hash tables with lambdas). For that reason, I **STRONGLY** recommend you not copy this code to turn in.

Comment: Oh, dude! Don't do his homework for him! Teach him about classes, but don't give code he can just copy and paste. That won't help him at all.

Comment: @BryanOakley as I mentioned at the bottom of my code dump, a lot of the techniques I used here aren't really feasible for someone struggling with OOP, but serve to illustrate the structure. In addition to your EXCELLENT answer that laid out the fundamentals, I feel like seeing a bit of completed code especially code that completes the intended assignment allows for more complete understanding. Teach fundamentals and theory, then teach implementation, then teach design and mastery. In any case, if he were to copy my code the only one losing out would be him....

Comment: @BryanOakley besides I defy you to find an instructor of a beginning programming class who will see `{'2': lambda x: self.zoo.getAnimal(input("index #: "))}[in_]()` and not IMMEDIATELY cry plaigiarism :)

Comment: I am NOT going to just copy this code... I really want to learn this stuff, I plan on taking future computer science courses. However, I am going to try and figure out exactly what is going on in his code that is parallel to what I'm learning in class, what makes it work, and what I'm doing wrong. So thank you Adam.